# I just bought a house and I see a gas line, 110v and 220v outlet in the laundry room. Does this mean I can install either a gas or electric dryer?

Tags: dryer, laundry

[image]Laundry room with gas and/or dryer.

[image: gas & 220v]

[image: washer hookups & 110v outlet]

(brighten up outlet pic - Harper)

[image]

Comment: While it appears to have gas available contact the gas company to verify it is usable.  My home has a gas line but the local gas company told  me it had been out of use for too long to be serviceable.

Comment: Is there a vent connection at the dryer location?

Comment: Certain washing machines use 220/240 VAC also (Like an Asko).

Comment: @mikes, might want to expand on that... if you turn on a valve and gas comes out, I don't know what else you would need to check.

Answer (score 12):

You are in luck. Yes, you can install either. The electric outlet is 4-wire, 2 hots, a neutral and a ground. It's always a good idea to verify it's wired correctly. A gas dryer will also require a 120V outlet.

Comment: re: "*A gas dryer will also require a 120V outlet.*"  And luckily, there is one - the plate for the washer includes two outlets.  Often a laundry room will only have one, but this one has two, so you're all set either way.

Answer (score 8):

I would say it looks like it is set up for a gas dryer. A few quick questions- where is the vent for gas fumes (some pilot free don’t need them) but they need make up air to exhaust. I would put a cap on that fitting just in case a cap is cheep insurance until hooked up.

Comment: I was surprised to see an un-capped gas fitting.  I just had a gas stove temporarily disconnected in order to tile under it, and the plumber insisted on capping it.  I suspect that whoever removed the dryer may not have cared so much as my plumber.

Comment: FWIW [most gas dryers do not need an insulated vent](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/56258/55930) and just exhaust the gasses outside with the normal moisture vent. I'd be surprised to see any gas dryers not using electric start for the burner.

Comment: @Machavity , yes pilot gas dryers are still a thing I have a daughter that has one and the reason I mentioned this in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If you do not want/use the gas(check what kind) probably will want a dust cap on the valve.

If not wanting the 240 volt plug, should turn off the breaker for it.

I would have prefer to have a red handle on the hot water faucet, but I might be getting too picky.

Some places are trying stop new gas hookups, but since it is already there, should/might be okay.

Comment: "Some places are trying stop new gas hookups". The Netherlands already stopped this in 2018, and the rest of the EU will likely follow.

Comment: Those are North American style plugs, so it's very unlikely that The Netherlands or EU directives will apply to the OP.

Comment: And some places are trying to ban banning new gas hook ups https://www.texastribune.org/2021/05/18/texas-natural-gas-bans-climate-plans/

Comment: New York State is in the process/or thinking about it, also to limit new gas/fossil fuel connections.  Think the plan is to go all electric in the future.

Comment: You should reword "Some places are trying stop new gas hookups" to be less ambiguous. What we're looking at is one branch off of the trunk so there is already gas at the house so you are free to use it as you see fit. The only major anti-gas law so far is that new construction is not allowed to have a utility gas supply. This will vary from region to region. Yes, that branch could be damaged beyond usability for reasons unknown but chances are high that the house has a functioning gas supply coming into it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel There is a vent for the dryer